# In what ways do we get out of if/else condition? java

Tags: java, if-statement

I did this code:

```
private static void fix (List<String> hg){

        String k1 = hg.get(0);
        String k2 = hg.get(1);
        String k3 = hg.get(2);
        String k4 = hg.get(3);
        String k5 = hg.get(4);

        List <Character> d = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < k1.length(); j++) {
                d.add(j, k1.charAt(j));
            }

Iterator <Character> sdf = d.iterator();
while (sdf.hasNext()){
  Character r = sdf.next();
  if (r.equals('g')){
    hg.add(k1);
  }
  if (r.equals('d')){
    hg.remove(k1);
  }
  if (r.equals('g') || r.equals('d')){ }// how to get out of this "if" beyond what I did?

}
```

upd: we check an array of words. If a word contains 'g' it should be doubled. If a word contains 'd' it should be deleted. If a word contains 'g' and 'd' it should be ignored. In my case any word containing 'd' or 'g' 2 or more times will be doubled or deleted or added. I guess the problem of this code is the third "if", where we search both 'd' and 'g' in a word.

The main idea is to ignore words containing letters 'g' and 'd'.

I know that we can use such methods like:

1. `if (r.equals('g') || r.equals('d')){ continue; }`
2. `if (r.equals('g') || r.equals('d')){ break; }`
3. `if (r.equals('g') || r.equals('d')){ System.out.println(); }`

3 of them are useless, cause idea tells that operator `continue` is unnecessary as the last statement in a loop. Operator `break` is not appropriate, cause it literally breaks the code and it won't work correctly.
`System.out.println()` fits well, but it makes a huge space in the console.

Comment: I think `break` should work, the problem is that your outer loop is wrong.  We'd need complete code to be sure, but you appear to be checking characters, not words, so you also need a loop that handles the words.  Please add some sample input and complete runnable code so we can see what is actually going on.

Comment: Look into the difference between `if` and `if...else`

Comment: It would be best to show a minimal reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You don't seem to have anything that suggests you're dealing with words.  Really, if you had a sequence of words, a `filter` would let you get rid of those you didn't want.

Comment: @markspace no problem, I added sample inputs  this code is quite huge though. I know it looks strange, but I want to test Iterator in this case. I faced this problem a lot so I need to learn how to get out such if/else conditions

Comment: Yes. If you're bailing on the iteration of an entire word, then that approach is inefficient. The character could appear anywhere, including the end

Comment: @g00se yep, I know that it's kind of inefficient. I'm trying to discover Iterator and its opportunities. I tried simple for/if code. It worked. I think that Iterator may work in this case as well.

Comment: Also, you're going to get errors with doubled (or more) letters

Comment: @g00se In this answer Mohammad added "else if" -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77168156/22625707. It works, but "continue" is still unnecessary. Actually, never got an error. I used characters 'g' and 'd' 2 and more times in a word.

Comment: @g00se oh, I just tried to use word "dgdter" and it was doubled by adding in an array (hg.add(k1)). So, yep, it still ain't work correctly.

Comment: I don't understand this question in the slightest. what does "get out of the condition" mean? do you have an example of the result you're trying to achieve, with a given input?

Comment: @user85421 I mean that we check an array of words. If a word contains 'g' it should be doubled. If a word contains 'd' it should be deleted. If a word contains 'g' and 'd' it should be ignored. In my case any word containing 'd' or 'g' 2 or more times will be doubled or deleted or added. I guess the problem is the third "if", where we search both 'd' and 'g' in a word.

Comment: @njzk2 I answered user85421 in more detail about the question.

Comment: @SecurityAlert this should be edited in the question directly, please

Comment: @njzk2 updated 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... The main idea is to ignore words containing letters 'g' and 'd'. ..."*

Qualify *r* by asserting it is not *g* or *d*, then delegate its value.

```java
if (!r.equals('g') && !r.equals('d')) {
    if (r.equals('л')){
        hg.add(k1);
    }
    if (r.equals('р')){
        hg.remove(k1);
    }
}
```

It's typically a good idea to use a *switch statement*, when you have similar *if-statements*.

For example.

```java
if (!r.equals('g') && !r.equals('d')) {
    switch (r) {
        case 'л' -> hg.add(k1);
        case 'р' -> hg.remove(k1);
    }
}
```

Alternately, you could add a *case* for both *g* and *d*, with an empty *code-block*.

```java
switch (r) {
    case 'g', 'd' -> { }
    case 'л' -> hg.add(k1);
    case 'р' -> hg.remove(k1);
}
```

This topic is referred to as *"control-flow"*.
Here are some relevant links.

- *[Wikipedia – Control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)*
- *[Control Flow Statements (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)*

As a recommendation, the *for-loop* on *k1* can be simplified to a *stream*.

```java
d = k1.chars().mapToObj(x -> (char) x).toList()
```

Or, just use a *char[]* rather than a *String*.

```java
char[] k1 = hg.get(0).toCharArray();
for (char r : k1) {
    switch (r) {
        case 'g', 'd' -> { }
        case 'л' -> hg.add(new String(k1));
        case 'р' -> hg.remove(new String(k1));
    }
}
```

Comment: alright, thank you!

Comment: I tried switch (r) in my case and duplicate case label popped up, cause you had to use 'g' and 'd' in the second and the third cases.

Comment: anyway, asserting "r" as it's not 'g' or 'd' worked for me 

Answer (score 1):

You should use `else if`, then you can apply the `continue` command:

```
Iterator<Character> sdf = d.iterator();
while (sdf.hasNext()) {
    Character r = sdf.next();
    if (r.equals('л')) {
        hg.add(k1);
    } else if (r.equals('р')) {
        hg.remove(k1);
    } else if (r.equals('g') || r.equals('d')) {
       continue;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Not quite. The last test should be first

Comment: using this code we should change the condition `else if (r.equals('g') | r.equals('d')) { continue; }` Anyway, continue is still unnecessary.

Comment: @SecurityAlert "using this code we should change the condition" (to a single `|` instead of 2). no. but also, why do you think that?

Comment: @njzk2 cause it compares object against the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Character object that represents the same char value as this object.

Comment: @SecurityAlert do I understand correctly that you are suggesting to use `else if (r.equals('g') | r.equals('d')) {` instead of `else if (r.equals('g') || r.equals('d')) {`? (If not, I don't understand your previous comment)

Comment: @njzk2 yep, we should use "|" instead of "||" in Mohammad's example. Otherwise, IJ Idea highlights the code explaining it as I answered you before.

Comment: I doubt it, though: `|` in this context just means not doing the short-circuit, which is only relevant if the second comparison has side effects

Answer (score 0):

No need to use 2nd loop at all. You could use `String.indexOf()` instead.

Using functional programming

```java
public static List<String> filter(List<String> words) {
    return words.stream()
                .filter(word -> {
                    word = word.toLowerCase();
                    return !(word.indexOf('g') >= 0 && word.indexOf('d') >= 0);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Not using functional programming

```java
public static List<String> filter(List<String> words) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(words.size());

    for (String word : words) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        
        if (!(word.indexOf('g') >= 0 && word.indexOf('d') >= 0))
            res.add(word);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Or, _if (word.indexOf('g') + word.indexOf('d') != -2)_.

Comment: that looks like another level of programming lol thank you anyway! I'll get back to this answer after some time